How to declare variable by using for-next loop
The following code is very good.
Sub Macro1()

'Convert plain excel data to Excel Table. (Excel workbook consist of 3 sheets)
For i = 1 To 3
    Worksheets(i).Select
    Worksheets(i).ListObjects.Add SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=Range("A1:C50"), XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes
Next i

'Load data from Excel Table to Variant
Dim Variant1 As Variant
Variant1 = Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange

Dim Variant2 As Variant
Variant2 = Worksheets(2).ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange

Dim Variant3 As Variant
Variant3 = Worksheets(3).ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange

'Loop through each item in Third Column of Table
Dim x1 As Long
For x1 = LBound(Variant1) To UBound(Variant1)
    Debug.Print Variant1(x1, 3)
Next x1

Dim x2 As Long
For x2 = LBound(Variant2) To UBound(Variant2)
    Debug.Print Variant2(x2, 3)
Next x2

Dim x3 As Long
For x3 = LBound(Variant3) To UBound(Variant3)
    Debug.Print Variant3(x3, 3)
Next x3

End Sub

I want to shorten the above code.
The following codes need to be repaired.
Sub Macro2()

'Load data from Excel Table to Variant

For i = 1 To 3
    'The following codes need to be repaired.
    'Dim "Variant" & i As Variant
    '"Variant" & i = Worksheets(i).ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
Next i

End Sub

I have tried an alternate approach using Scripting.Dictionary as BigBen recommended. But the following code needs to be repaired.
Sub Macro3()

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = Nothing
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.RemoveAll
    
    For i = 1 To 3
        dict.Add Key:=i, Item:=Worksheets(i).ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
    Next i
     
End Sub


This isn't possible. An alternate approach is to use a Scripting.Dictionary.

Set dict = Nothing and dict.RemoveAll are redundant. Add .Value after .DataBodyRange.

You can use an array:
Sub Macro3()
    Dim myInteger As Integer
    Dim data() As Variant, i As Long, r As Long, arr
    
    myInteger = 3
    ReDim data(1 To myInteger) 'can't `Dim` using a variable...
    
    For i = 1 To myInteger
        data(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Value
    Next i
    
    For i = 1 To myInteger
        arr = data(i)
        For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            Debug.Print arr(r, 3)
        Next r
    Next i
End Sub


Loop Through Specific Data Column After Converting to Excel Table (ListObject)
Before

After

Sub ConvertToTables()
    
    Debug.Print "Running ""ConvertToTables""..."
    
    Const SEARCH_COLUMN As Long = 3

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' If it's not, specify it correctly.
    ' If it's the active workbook, use 'Set wb = ActiveWorkbook' instead.

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rg As Range, lo As ListObject
    Dim Data As Variant, rCount As Long, r As Long
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        On Error Resume Next
            Set lo = ws.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, _
                Source:=rg, XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not lo Is Nothing Then
            rCount = lo.ListRows.Count
            If rCount > 0 And lo.ListColumns.Count >= SEARCH_COLUMN Then
                Debug.Print ws.Name, lo.Name
                ' Either...
                With lo.ListColumns(SEARCH_COLUMN).DataBodyRange
                    If rCount = 1 Then ' single row
                        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
                        Data(1, 1) = .Value
                    Else ' multiple rows
                        Data = .Value
                    End If
                End With
                For r = 1 To rCount
                    Debug.Print r, rCount, Data(r, 1)
                Next r
                ' ... or, if you need the values in the other columns:
                'Data = lo.DataBodyRange.Value
                'For r = 1 To rCount
                '    Debug.Print r, Data(r, SEARCH_COLUMN)
                'Next r
            Else ' no data
                Debug.Print "Table """ & lo.Name & """ has no data."
            End If
            Set lo = Nothing
        Else
            Debug.Print "... probably overlaps with an existing table"
        End If
    Next ws
        
End Sub

Sub ConvertToRanges()
    
    Debug.Print "Running ""ConvertToRanges""..."
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' If it's not, specify it correctly.
    ' If it's the active workbook, use 'Set wb = ActiveWorkbook' instead.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lo As ListObject, RangeRowsCount As Long
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if table doesn't exist
            Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not lo Is Nothing Then ' table exists
            Debug.Print "Clearing table """ & lo.Name & """!"
            RangeRowsCount = lo.ListRows.Count + 1
            If RangeRowsCount = 1 Then RangeRowsCount = 2
            lo.Unlist
            ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(RangeRowsCount).ClearFormats
            Set lo = Nothing
        Else ' table doesn't exist
            Debug.Print "No table found in """ & ws.Name & """!"
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub


After running each procedure twice in a row, the Immediate window (Ctrl+G) showed:

Running "ConvertToTables"...
Sheet1        Table1
 1             4             34 
 2             4             48 
 3             4             14 
 4             4             74 
Sheet2        Table2
 1             3             70 
 2             3             17 
 3             3             84 
Table "Table3" has no data.
Running "ConvertToTables"...
... probably overlaps with an existing table
... probably overlaps with an existing table
... probably overlaps with an existing table
Running "ConvertToRanges"...
Clearing table "Table1"!
Clearing table "Table2"!
Clearing table "Table3"!
Running "ConvertToRanges"...
No table found in "Sheet1"!
No table found in "Sheet2"!
No table found in "Sheet3"!

